# How to remove unique rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
index                                            SUBJECT
1                                                   test
2                                                  Hello
3                                                  Hello
4                               PRC review - phone calls
```

AFTER REMOVING

```
index                                            SUBJECT
2                                                  Hello
3                                                  Hello
```

I want to delete rows based on only the "SUBJECT" column.
How to do this?

Comment: can you explain more? 
You want to achieve second  dataframe from the firstone?

Comment: yes i want to  remove unique rows in 1st dataframe to make it look like 2nd one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this:

`df.loc[(df.groupby('SUBJECT').count()>1).sum(axis=1),:]`

Answer (score 4):

Use `duplicated`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"SUBJECT": ["test", "Hello", "Hello", "PRC review - phone calls"]})
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=["SUBJECT"], keep=False)]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  SUBJECT
1   Hello
2   Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
# get count for each value
s = df.SUBJECT.value_counts()

# get only those that appear more than once
repeated = set(s[s > 1].index.values)

# filter the data-frame base
result = df[df.SUBJECT.isin(repeated)]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   index SUBJECT
1      2   Hello
2      3   Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

using loc..

```
>>> df.loc[df.duplicated(keep=False), :]
  SUBJECT
1   Hello
2   Hello
```

### Solution 2:

Another way with **groupby** + **transform** ..

```
>>> df[df.groupby('SUBJECT')['SUBJECT'].transform('size') > 1]
  SUBJECT
1   Hello
2   Hello
```